# Rails: Validation error messages are not displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails, trying to learn by creating a simple test project where I am trying to display validation error messages on my browser. The problem is that the messages are not getting displayed. I am referring to this [**blog**](https://medium.com/@javsteratii/how-to-show-errors-to-the-user-when-using-forms-in-rails-db85689f17a4)

```rb
#app/controller/dogs.rb
def create
  @dog = Dog.new(dog_params)
  if @dog.save
    redirect_to dog_path(@dog)
  else
    p @dog.errors.inspect
    render :new
  end
end

# app/models/dog.rb
class Dog < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :age, presence: true
end
```

```
<!-- app/views/dogs/new.html.erb -->
<h1>CREATE NEW PUP!</h1>

<%= @dog.errors.inspect %>
<% if @dog.errors.any? %>
  <% @dog.errors.full_messages.each do |message|%>
    <h3><%= message %></h3>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<br />

<%= form_for @dog do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :NAME %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.label :AGE%>
  <%= f.text_field :age%>
  <br />
  <%= f.submit "SUBMIT" %>
<% end %>
```

I have 2 observations:

1. If I go to the networks DevTool in chrome and then check the preview tab, I can see that the error messages are being rendered in the preview tab. But I can't see them on the main browser/output. Tried with multiple browsers. Same result.
2. Upon printing `@dog.errors.inspect` from the controller to the terminal, I can see the errors. But when using `@dog.errors.inspect` on the view, the errors[] is empty.

Comment: If you see the HTML in the preview but not rendered in the browser, the only logical explanation is an HTML / CSS issue causing a rendering issue. Double-check all the HTML (end tags), also inspect your layout.

Comment: Hi Paulo, Thank you for replying. I have checked all HTML files and don't have any CSS files. I have not made any changes to any other files. Just copied the contents of these 3 files from the blog above.  Other files are generated using the scaffold.

Comment: You're missing an `<% end %>` tag after `<% @dog.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>`. Also while the parser doesn't care if you write ` <%end%>` its seen as bad style.

Comment: I think @PauloAbreu is also spot on - its most likely a HTML error such as an unclosed tag. Use a [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/) to find the problem(s). You can also do a lot better when it comes to actually marking up and grouping content such as inputs and labels together. Do not use `<br>` except to actually add breaks to text blocks.

Comment: `errors.inspect` is going to generate a string that looks something like `<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007f795b5fff38 @base=...>` which, if it's in HTML is going to be interpreted as an HTML tag with no contents in it.  It looks like your use of `full_messages` is correct.

Comment: @mrrogers I can see the contents of ```errors.inspect``` when I print them from my controller. But on HTML I get ```#<ActiveModel::Errors []>```. If I'm not wrong, the instance variable ```@dog``` and its contents ```@dog.errors``` should be available by default in the view, right? Why are they empty? And how can I pass them to the HTML?

Comment: @max I checked again with the HTML validator. Nothing seems off. All tags are properly closed. And yes I rarely ever use the </br> tag, I was just trying to be true to the blog that I'm referring. Also, the ```@dog.errors``` is empty in the view (new.html.erb). Because of that ```if @dog.errors.any?``` this line is returning false and nothing below gets executed. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: @max Also I have 2 ```<% end %>``` tags. Do I need an ```<% end %>``` tag for ```<%= @dog.errors.inspect %>``` as well?

Comment: Your HTML seems ok, there must be something else but is hard to tell without seeing all the code.

Comment: I can share all the code if you want. But that will be a lot of code. I have only made changes to these files and the model file.

Comment: The code here will not actually reproduce the issue so its most likely something wonky going on off in the margins. For example `@dog` could be resassigned somewhere to a new instance. IMHO that blog post is pretty bad and this is stuff that the [Rails guides covers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views) better. I really don't like stuff like `<%= f.label :NAME %>` which breaks the I18n integration and crappy markup. You would be better off just scaffolding the code...

Comment: I mean if you want a good example just run `rails g scaffold dog name age:integer`

Comment: +1 on experiencing this same issue, so weird. I also see the errors on preview, yet don't render. I see an odd error in JS console: `turbo.es2017-esm.js:2406 Error: Form responses must redirect to another location` 